# Display events in custom calendar as dot image

Tags: android, calendar, adapter

I want to show events in my custom calendar as a dot image. And the event date is coming from json parsing and i have added that date to hashmap arraylist. Then after i have set that arraylist to my Calendar adapter but at that moments its give me null pointer and in my custom calendar nothing display. so please any standard solution to solve this??

```
  public class Event extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

GridView gv;
public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;
String itemvalue;
int Category_id;
public CalendarAdapter adapter;
public Handler handler;
public ArrayList<String> items;
RelativeLayout previous, next;
private static final int ID_ADD_EVENT = 1;
private static final int ID_PERSONAL = 2;
private static final int ID_BUSINESS = 3;
private static final int ID_MISC = 4;
private static final int ID_TODAY = 5;
Button btnSlideMenu, btnAction;
QuickAction quickAction;
InputStream is;
View v;
HashMap<String, String> map;
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
String success, message, feed_id, feedtitle, description, type, eventDate,
        categoryId, userid, username;
InterNetConnectionDetector isNet = new InterNetConnectionDetector(
        getActivity());

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events, container, false);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy stp = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(stp);

    }

    try {
        new EventData().execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    Log.v("Size", eventList.size() + "");
    adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), month, eventList);

    gv = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendar);
    previous = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.previous);
    next = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    btnAction = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
    btnSlideMenu = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSildeMenu);
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAction.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSlideMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
    gv.setAdapter(adapter);
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater);

    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
            String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                    .get(position);
            String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
            String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                    "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
            int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
            // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
            if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
            ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

            showToast(selectedGridDate);

            /*
             * if (desc.size() > 0) { for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++)
             * { TextView rowTextView = new TextView(CalendarView.this);
             * 
             * // set some properties of rowTextView or something
             * rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
             * rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
             * 
             * // add the textview to the linearlayout
             * rLayout.addView(rowTextView);
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * }
             */

            // desc = null;

        }
    });
    ActionItem nextItem = new ActionItem(ID_ADD_EVENT, "Add New Event",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
    ActionItem prevItem = new ActionItem(ID_PERSONAL, "Personal", null);
    ActionItem searchItem = new ActionItem(ID_BUSINESS, "Business", null);
    ActionItem infoItem = new ActionItem(ID_MISC, "Misc", null);
    ActionItem todayItem = new ActionItem(ID_TODAY, "Today", null);

    prevItem.setSticky(true);
    nextItem.setSticky(true);

    quickAction = new QuickAction(getActivity(), QuickAction.VERTICAL);

    // add action items into QuickAction
    quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
    quickAction.addActionItem(prevItem);
    quickAction.addActionItem(searchItem);
    quickAction.addActionItem(infoItem);
    quickAction.addActionItem(todayItem);

    // Set listener for action item clicked
    quickAction
            .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(QuickAction source, int pos,
                        int actionId) {
                    ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);

                    if (actionId == ID_ADD_EVENT) {

                        Intent n = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Add_Event.class);
                        startActivity(n);

                    } else if (actionId == ID_PERSONAL) {

                    } else if (actionId == ID_BUSINESS) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Let's do some search action",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (actionId == ID_MISC) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "I have no info this time",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                actionItem.getTitle() + " selected",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    quickAction.dismiss();
                }

            });

    quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed",
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */
        }
    });
    return v;
}

/*
 * @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // TODO
 * Auto-generated method stub super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 * setContentView(R.layout.events);
 * 
 * if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) { getActionBar().hide(); } if
 * (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 8) {
 * 
 * StrictMode.ThreadPolicy stp = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
 * .permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(stp);
 * 
 * }
 * 
 * try { new EventData().execute(); } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle
 * exception }
 * 
 * Locale.setDefault(Locale.US); month = (GregorianCalendar)
 * GregorianCalendar.getInstance(); itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar)
 * month.clone();
 * 
 * items = new ArrayList<String>(); adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this,
 * month);
 * 
 * gv = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar); previous =
 * (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous); next = (RelativeLayout)
 * findViewById(R.id.next); btnAction = (Button)
 * findViewById(R.id.btnAction); btnSlideMenu = (Button)
 * findViewById(R.id.btnSildeMenu); TextView title = (TextView)
 * findViewById(R.id.title);
 * title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
 * previous.setOnClickListener(this); next.setOnClickListener(this);
 * btnAction.setOnClickListener(this);
 * btnSlideMenu.setOnClickListener(this); gv.setAdapter(adapter); handler =
 * new Handler(); handler.post(calendarUpdater);
 * 
 * gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { public void
 * onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 * 
 * ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v); String
 * selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString .get(position); String[]
 * separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-"); String gridvalueString =
 * separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");// taking last part of date. ie;
 * 2 from 2012-12-02. int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString); //
 * navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays. if ((gridvalue >
 * 10) && (position < 8)) { setPreviousMonth(); refreshCalendar(); } else if
 * ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) { setNextMonth(); refreshCalendar();
 * } ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
 * 
 * showToast(selectedGridDate);
 * 
 * } }); ActionItem nextItem = new ActionItem(ID_ADD_EVENT, "Add New Event",
 * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.plus)); ActionItem prevItem = new
 * ActionItem(ID_PERSONAL, "Personal", null); ActionItem searchItem = new
 * ActionItem(ID_BUSINESS, "Business", null); ActionItem infoItem = new
 * ActionItem(ID_MISC, "Misc", null); ActionItem todayItem = new
 * ActionItem(ID_MISC, "Today", null);
 * 
 * prevItem.setSticky(true); nextItem.setSticky(true);
 * 
 * quickAction = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.VERTICAL);
 * 
 * // add action items into QuickAction quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
 * quickAction.addActionItem(prevItem);
 * quickAction.addActionItem(searchItem);
 * quickAction.addActionItem(infoItem);
 * quickAction.addActionItem(todayItem);
 * 
 * // Set listener for action item clicked quickAction
 * .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener()
 * {
 * 
 * @Override public void onItemClick(QuickAction source, int pos, int
 * actionId) { ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
 * 
 * if (actionId == ID_ADD_EVENT) {
 * 
 * Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Add_Event.class);
 * startActivity(n);
 * 
 * } else if (actionId == ID_PERSONAL) {
 * 
 * } else if (actionId == ID_BUSINESS) {
 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Let's do some search action",
 * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } else if (actionId == ID_MISC) {
 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I have no info this time",
 * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } else {
 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actionItem.getTitle() +
 * " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
 * 
 * quickAction.dismiss(); }
 * 
 * });
 * 
 * quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
 * 
 * @Override public void onDismiss() {
 * 
 * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismissed",
 * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 * 
 * } }); }
 */
protected void setNextMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    }

}

protected void setPreviousMonth() {
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }

}

protected void showToast(String string) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void refreshCalendar() {
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

    adapter.refreshDays();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

    title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
}

public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        items.clear();

        // Print dates of the current week
        /*
         * SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
         * Locale.US);
         * 
         * for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) { itemvalue =
         * df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
         * itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
         * items.add("2012-09-12"); items.add("2012-10-07");
         * items.add("2012-10-15"); items.add("2012-10-20");
         * items.add("2012-11-30"); items.add("2012-11-28"); }
         */
        // adapter.setMoreItems(eventList);
        adapter.setItems(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.previous:
        setPreviousMonth();
        refreshCalendar();
        break;

    case R.id.next:
        setNextMonth();
        refreshCalendar();
        break;

    case R.id.btnAction:
        quickAction.show(v);
        break;

    case R.id.btnSildeMenu:
        try {
            Sliding.viewActionsContentView.showActions();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

public class EventData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // data=jobj.toString();
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity()
                .getSharedPreferences("ID", 0);
        Category_id = pref.getInt("catId", 1);

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "http://www.sevenstarinfotech.com/projects/demo/GetConnected/api/all_events.php?&fromdate='2013-05-26'&todate='2013-07-06'&category_id="
                    + Category_id;
            Log.v("Event URL", url);
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httppost.addHeader("app-key",
                    "b51bc98b4d6fd0456f7f1b17278415fa49de57d5");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();

                result = sb.toString();
                Log.v("Response is:", result);
            } catch (Exception e3) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e3.toString());
            }

            // parse json data
            try {
                JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject jdata = ja.getJSONObject("data");

                success = jdata.getString("Success");
                message = jdata.getString("Message");

                JSONArray jArray = jdata.getJSONArray("Eventdetails");
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject meJson = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("sucess", success);
                    map.put("message", message);
                    feed_id = meJson.getString("feedid");
                    feedtitle = meJson.getString("feedtitle");
                    description = meJson.getString("description");
                    type = meJson.getString("type");
                    eventDate = meJson.getString("eventdate");
                    categoryId = meJson.getString("categoryid");
                    userid = meJson.getString("userid");
                    username = meJson.getString("username");
                    eventList.add(map);

                }

                Log.v("EvenitList Size", eventList.size() + "");
                Log.v("Json Data:", jArray + "");

                // int status = Integer.parseInt(success);

                // if (status == 1) {

                // } else {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status = 0,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // }

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                Log.e("log_tag",
                        "Error in http connection " + e1.toString());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

**My Adapter Class:**

```
 public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
private java.util.Calendar month;
public GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
public GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
int firstDay;
int maxWeeknumber;
int maxP;
int calMaxP;
int lastWeekDay;
int leftDays;
int mnthlength;
String itemvalue, curentDateString;
DateFormat df;
private ArrayList<String> items;
public static List<String> dayString;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> events;
private View previousView;

public CalendarAdapter(Context c, GregorianCalendar monthCalendar,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList) {
    CalendarAdapter.dayString = new ArrayList<String>();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    month = monthCalendar;
    selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) monthCalendar.clone();
    mContext = c;
    month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.events = eventList;
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
    refreshDays();
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<String> items) {
    for (int i = 0; i != items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).length() == 1) {
            items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));

        }
    }
    this.items = items;
}

public void setMoreItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> events) {
    for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
        if (events.get(i).size() == 1) {

            HashMap<String, String> mydata = new HashMap<String, String>();

            items.set(i, "0" + items.get(i));
            mydata.values().add(items.toString());
            events.add(mydata);

        }
    }
    this.events = events;
}

public int getCount() {

    return dayString.size() & events.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// create a new view for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);

    }
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    // separates daystring into parts.
    String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(position).split("-");
    // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
    String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
    // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
    if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (position < firstDay)) {
        // setting offdays to white color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#98AFC7"));
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (position > 28)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#98AFC7"));
        dayView.setClickable(false);
        dayView.setFocusable(false);
    } else {
        // setting curent month's days in blue color.
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#6D7B8D"));
    }

    if (dayString.get(position).equals(curentDateString)) {
        setSelected(v);
        previousView = v;
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
    }
    dayView.setText(gridvalue);

    // create date string for comparison
    String date = dayString.get(position);

    if (date.length() == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    String monthStr = "" + (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
    if (monthStr.length() == 1) {
        monthStr = "0" + monthStr;
    }
    /*
     * ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon); if
     * (date.length() > 0 && events != null && events.contains(date)) {
     * iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } else {
     * iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); }
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
        ImageView iw = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_icon);
        if (date.length() > 0 && events != null
                && events.get(i).get("eventdate").equalsIgnoreCase(date)) {
            iw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            iw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    return v;
}

public View setSelected(View view) {
    if (previousView != null) {
        previousView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);

    }
    previousView = view;
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_cel_selectl);
    return view;
}

public void refreshDays() {
    // clear items
    items.clear();
    dayString.clear();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
    firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // finding number of weeks in current month.
    maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
    mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
    maxP = getMaxP();
    calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...

    pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();

    pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

    for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

        itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
        pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        dayString.add(itemvalue);

    }
}

private int getMaxP() {
    int maxP;
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }
    maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return maxP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **calendarUpdater**, what would happen if you wrote this..

```
adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), month, eventList);
gv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: after the Eventdata function execute I wrote.                        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), month, eventList);        And i also print the size of eventlist in log but it displayed 0.

Comment: Is the eventList always 0? Why you set it **static**?

Comment: **static** so it can't be modify?!

Comment: maybe this would help - http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listing-images-in-gridview-using-simple-adapter-in-android/